# How do I get partial cumulative sums of a column grouped by another two columns in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy array:

```py
a = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,2,10],[1,2,20],[2,1,30],[2,1,40]])

array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  2],
       [ 1,  1,  3],
       [ 1,  2, 10],
       [ 1,  2, 20],
       [ 2,  1, 30],
       [ 2,  1, 40]])
```

I would like to do a cumulative sum across 3rd column but grouped by columns 1 and 2.

So I would get:

```py
array([[ 1,  1,  6],
       [ 1,  2, 30],
       [ 2,  1, 70]])
```

While this can be done iterating and using a hashmap structure, I am wondering if there is a way to solve this using numpy.

Comment: Should be simple with pandas. Try that?

Comment: I  am learning numpy and I want to know if there is a way to do it in numpy.

Comment: Would they be positive numbers in first two cols?

Comment: No, not necessarily. But they will be always sorted.

Comment: Would they be integers?

Comment: No, actually in the "real" example they are float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We can use [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) + [`np.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
In [18]: u,tags = np.unique(a[:,:2], return_inverse=True, axis=0)

In [21]: np.hstack((u,np.bincount(tags, a[:,2])[:,None].astype(a.dtype)))
Out[21]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  6],
       [ 1,  2, 30],
       [ 2,  1, 70]])
```

Skip `.astype(a.dtype)` if the data is already floats.

**Approach #2**

Use sorted nature, with `np.add.reduceat` -

```
In [57]: idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,(a[:-1,:2] != a[1:,:2]).any(1)])

In [58]: np.hstack((a[idx,:2], np.add.reduceat(a[:,2], idx)[:,None]))
Out[58]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  6],
       [ 1,  2, 30],
       [ 2,  1, 70]])
```

Comment: Brilliant and really useful. It is not an easy operation at all.